# Passing JSP variable to Java function?

Tags: java, jsp

I am working with a JSP file, trying to work on a simple logon page.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="com.bridge.service.*" %>
<!-- needs to be run on server to resolve both errors -->
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
    <title>Login </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" name="frmLogon">
        User Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="<c:out value="${email}" />" /> <br /> 
        Password: <input type="text" name="password" value="<c:out value="${password}" />" /> <br />
        <jsp:useBean id="link" scope="application" class="com.bridge.service.Service" />
        <% 
            Service s = new Service();
            String token = s.logonToken(email, password);
        %>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am having a hard time understanding how to take the two values from the POST form and passing them to the Java function. Is this possible? Am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: are you using any framework or is it a simple servlet. simple servlet you can get it from request.getParameter("email"); if you are using some framework, you need to bind the object to the data model and retrieve the value in the backend

Comment: It's just a simple servlet. Should I pass the values as `s.logonToken(request.getParameter(email), request.getParameter(password));`?

Answer (score 1):

For simple servlet, you shouod use:

```
String email = (String)request.getParameter("email");
String password = (String)request.getParameter("password");
```